# Convert a dataset (or a custom collection) into a sitemap

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap, sitemapprovider

I have generic collection list, which has certain properties.... its a heirchachical collection, that I now I want to make into a sitemap file.... i.e., the standard one that MSDN states.... so the output will be something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581782.aspx

I know I can probably write an xml otuput using xslt, or xmldoc, but is there a way to do this using sitemapprovider and sitemapnode classes that .net framework provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer this URL

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15614/Building-and-Consuming-a-Dynamic-Sitemap-in-ASP-NE

Comment: XSLT for just  rendering purpose. if you want to  use other mechanism then you  could easily since you have the data in XML  form.